# Applications and methods for TerraSAR X

Tags: remote-sensing, radar

People who already used or are familiar with TerraSAR X, can you point out:

- Main applications and methods
- Open source software tools

Answer (score 3):

GDAL can read [TerraSAR-X Cosar](https://gdal.org/frmt_cosar.html) data, so technically, most opensource geospatial software can use this format.

Some specific opensource desktop application that can process TerraSAR-X are:

- [Orfeo ToolBox](https://wiki.orfeo-toolbox.org/index.php/Main_Page)
- [ESA NEST](https://web.archive.org/web/20210128090740/http://nest.array.ca/web/nest)
- [Radar Tools](https://web.archive.org/web/20130524151023/http://radartools.berlios.de/news.php)

Comment: good one! What about applications for these data?